I am trying simply to add a custom checkbox in WooCommerce checkout but it's not working
I am trying simply to add a custom checkbox in WooCommerce checkout with a classic code in the functions.php of my child theme but nothing appears on the checkout page.
In don't understand why. It's seems to work for everyone. I deactivate all my plugin, same thing. I turn back to Twenty two theme, same thing.
have I forgotten anything else?
I'm really sorry to bother you for such a small thing.
Wordpress 6.6.2
Woocommerce 9.3.3
Theme Neve Pro Child
The code i use in functions.php :
// Add custom checkout field: woocommerce_review_order_before_submit
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field() {
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'     => __('My custom checkbox'),
    ),  WC()->checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ) );
    echo '</div>';
}

// Save the custom checkout field in the order meta, when checkbox has been checked
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', $_POST['my_field_name'] );
}

// Display the custom field result on the order edit page (backend) when checkbox has been checked
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages( $order ){
    $my_field_name = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'my_field_name', true );
    if( $my_field_name == 1 )
        echo '<p><strong>My custom field: </strong> <span style="color:red;">Is enabled</span></p>';
}


add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'custom_content_below_billing_info');
here is one sample hook i used to show fields after billing form.
you are using woocommerce_review_order_before_submit
it is possible that you have modified the checkout template. if you use other checkout page hook for test and verify that those are working? but make sure  you hook have high priority
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_process', 5); // Lower number means higher priority
